# std::to_string offset from beginning of the line for each row

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I use std::to_string to print some numerical values(vectors, or matrices) in my terminal.

printer_func(to_string(m));

which will print:

```
[2011-12-22 11:34:30.441] [abcdefgho] [info] 0
     0
     0
1.5708
     0
     0
     0
```

or

```
[2021-12-22 11:34:30.441] [abcdefgho] [info] 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

However, I want it to print or give me the string with some offset for each line, for instance:

```
[2011-12-22 11:34:30.441] [abcdefgho] [info] 0
                                             0
                                             0
                                             1.5708
                                             0
                                             0
                                             0

[2011-12-22 11:34:30.441] [abcdefgho] [info] 
                                             0 0 0 0
                                             0 0 0 0
                                             0 0 0 0
                                             0 0 0 1
```

or even better with the possibility of including additional characters for all rows:

```
[2011-12-22 11:34:30.441] [abcdefgho] [info] | 0
                                             | 0
                                             | 0
                                             | 1.5708
                                             | 0
                                             | 0
                                             | 0

[2011-12-22 11:34:30.441] [abcdefgho] [info] 
                                             | 0 0 0 0
                                             | 0 0 0 0
                                             | 0 0 0 0
                                             | 0 0 0 1
```

Does anyone know an elegant way or another alternative for achieving this?

----edit

for printing I use spdlog

Comment: you want using `spdlog` to resolve your problem? or you want to using `cout` for achieve this?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz preferable I want the structure of the string to be modified already for the spdlog to include spaces when printing every row, because I doubt spdlog has its own solution for it. so something that will add the offset for each row

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/3.-Custom-formatting#aligning ?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz no it doesn't make any change for the later rows